# Is the dualizing sheaf on a Cohen-Macaulay scheme reflexive?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohen-macaulay-rings

I am reading the paper *Frobenius splitting of Hilbert schemes
of points on surfaces* by Kumar and Thomsen. At the end of Lemma 11, they seem to imply that the dualizing sheaf on a Cohen-Macaulay scheme is reflexive. I am not familiar with reflexive sheaves, so I would like to ask whether this statement is true or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is *yes*. Let me briefly explain why.

There are several ways to define a canonical sheaf on a projective variety $X$. One of them, that works for any *normal* $X$ is the following. Let $U$ be the smooth locus of $X$ and $i \colon U \hookrightarrow X$ be the natural inclusion. Then define $$\omega_X:=i_*(\Omega^n_U),$$
where $n:=\dim X$. As the sections of $\Omega^n_U$ do not
depend on a subset of codimension $2$, neither do the sections of $\omega_X$. In other words, $\omega_X$ is a so-called *normal sheaf*. Moreover, by construction $\omega_X$ is also torsion-free, so it is reflexive by the second characterization in [**1**, Proposition 1.6].

When $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay, this sheaf coincides with the dualizing sheaf in the sense of Serre duality. A different way to define a canonical sheaf for embedded varieties $X \subset \mathbb{P}^{N}$ is to consider $$\omega_X' := h^{-n}(\omega_X^{\bullet}),$$
where $\omega_X^{\bullet}$ is the so-called *dualizing complex*. Again, when $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay this construction provides a reflexive sheaf, that coincides with $\omega_X$ outside a subset of codimension $\geq 2$. Then reflexivity implies $$\omega_X'\simeq \omega_X,$$
see [**2**, Section 5].

**References.**

**[1]$\,$**  *Robin Hartshorne*, [**Stable reflexive sheaves**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01467074), *Math. Ann.* **254** (1980), no. 2, 121--176.

**[2] $\,$** *Sándor J. Kovács*, [**Singularities of stable varieties**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3184177), *Handbook of moduli. Vol. II* 159--203.

Comment: This seems to settle the question when $X$ is Cohen–Macaulay and normal (I think that [2] has this as a running assumption, at least when they mention reflexivity).

Comment: @Francesco, thanks for your explanation. I don't see immediately that your construction of canonical sheaf coincides with dualizing sheaf in the sense of Serre duality. I will write my partial proof to this statement in another question "dualizing sheaf on cohen-macaulay scheme". It would be great if you can take a look at it and point out what I missed.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, this does not need CM. The following is true:

> Let $Z$ be an excellent scheme that admits a dualizing complex. Then $ω_Z$ is torsion-free and $S_2$ on $Z$. If in addition Z is normal, then $ω_Z$ is a reflexive $\mathscr O_Z$ -module.

Also note that torsion-free and $S_2$ seems to be the "right" notion to replace reflexivity on non-normal schemes.

If there is interest in this, I will add a proof.

---

As requested, here is a proof:
(The following is Lemma 3.7.5 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02269).)

> **Lemma** Let $Z$ be an excellent scheme that admits a dualizing complex. Then $\omega_Z$ is torsion-free and $S_2$ on $Z$. If in addition $Z$ is normal, then $\omega_Z$ is a reflexive $\mathscr O_Z$-module.

> *Proof.* The statement is local, so we may assume that $Z$ is a noetherian affine local scheme.
> Then, since it admits a dualizing complex, it can be embedded into a finite dimensional Gorenstein affine local scheme W as a closed subscheme by [[Kaw02, Cor. 1.4]](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2002-354-01/S0002-9947-01-02817-3/S0002-9947-01-02817-3.pdf).
> Being Gorenstein and local, $W$ must be pure dimensional. Let $r = \mathrm{codim}(Z, W)$. Then
> by [[Mat80, (16.B) Theorem 31(i)]](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/commutative-ring-theory?format=PB#S3kQjWwLamaYB9ch.97) there exists a length $r$ regular sequence in the ideal of $Z$
> in $W$ and let $W'$ be the common zero locus. Then $W'$ is also Gorenstein,
> $Z\subseteq W$ is a closed subscheme and $\dim Z = \dim W$ .

> It follows that $\omega_ {W'}^\bullet \simeq
>   \omega_{W'}[m]$, where $\omega_{W'}$ is a line bundle on ${W'}$. By Grothendieck
> duality $\omega^\bullet_ Z\simeq RHom_{W'}(\mathscr O_Z, \omega^\bullet_{W'})$, and since $\dim Z=\dim W'$,
> $\omega_Z\simeq Hom_{W'}(\mathscr O_Z, \omega_{W'})$ hence it is indeed torsion-free on
> $Z$.

> By [[Stacks Project, Tag 0AWE]](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AWE)
> $\omega_Z$ is $S_2$. In particular, if $Z$ is normal, then it is reflexive by [[Stacks Project,Tag 0AVB]](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AVB).

---

As far as non-trivial examples of schemes admitting dualizing complexes are concerned, try anything that can be embedded (locally) into a Gorenstein scheme. In fact, those are exactly the ones you are looking for.

Comment: Certainly! In fact, I would be much more interested in seeing some natural examples in algebraic geometry which is not CM but is excellent and admits a dualizing complex.

Comment: Any finite type scheme over a field (or over an affine regular scheme) admits a dualizing complex and, of course they needn't be CM.